# Autocad revcloud type polygon edge

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, autocad

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to make a polygon edge in QGIS 2.18 look like an Autocad revcloud (shown in red).

[image: Revcloud example[1]]

I would prefer an edge that looks a little random over one that is made up of a single arc.

Comment: You may try to draw a raw polygon, then convert it to a line and finally use the code in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241856/87487): does it help?