# Geometry Generator using polygon boundary expression only returning Exterior Ring QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am using a custom QGIS expression function that creates a zigzag line.
See the function here: [Wavy Edge on polygon in QGIS using geometry generators](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367422/wavy-edge-on-polygon-in-qgis-using-geometry-generators)
The function needs a line string and not a polygon so I use the boundary expression like this:
[image: make_zigzagline(boundary($geometry),3,3)]
This works except if it has interior rings.
If the polygons have interior rings I get this error

> Eval Error: MultiLineString geometry cannot be converted to a
> polyline. Only single line or curve types are permitted.

And it only shows on polygons without rings.
[image: boundary only]
If use this expression instead:

```
collect_geometries(make_zigzagline(exterior_ring( $geometry),1.5,3), make_zigzagline(interior_ring_n( $geometry,1),1.5,3))
```

It only shows those polygons with at least one ring and doesn't show the second ring if it exists.
[image: exterior and 1st interior rings]

Is there some way I can have it figure out how many rings it has an use that?
Or is there something I can change in this function I can change to have it accept  MultiLineString geometry?

```
from qgis.core import qgsfunction,QgsExpressionContextUtils,QgsExpression,QgsProject,QgsPoint,QgsGeometry
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referencedColumns=[])
def make_zigzagline(geom,dist,offset,feature,parent):
    """
    <style>
    span { color: red }

    </style>
    <h2>converts a linestring to a zig-zag line</h2>

    make_zigzagline(<span>geometry</span>,<span>distance(s)</span>,<span>offset</span>)<br/>

    <table>
        <tr><td><span>geometry</span></td><td>linestring geometry</td></tr>
        <tr><td><span>distance(s)</span></td><td>linear point distances (single number or a string of comma separated numbers)</td></tr>
        <tr><td><span>offset</span></td><td>perpendicular offset</td></tr>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    Examples:
    <ul>
        <li>make_zigzagline($geometry,'15,30',15) -> zig-zag line</li>
        <li>make_zigzagline($geometry,15,15) -> zig-zag line</li>
    </ul>

    Use smooth function to create wavelines:<br/><br/>
    Example:
    <ul><li>smooth(make_zigzagline($geometry,'15,30',15),3)</li></ul>
    """

    if not type(dist) is str:
        dist = str(dist)

    dist = [float(n) for n in dist.split(',')]
    l = geom.length()
    dist_sum = 0
    distances = []
    while dist_sum + round(sum(dist),2) < l:
        for d in dist:
            dist_sum += d
            distances.append(dist_sum)

    # interpolate points on linestring
    points2d = [(lambda g: (g.x(), g.y()))(geom.interpolate(d).asPoint()) for d in distances]
    vertices = geom.asPolyline()
    start = (vertices[0].x(),vertices[0].y())
    end = (vertices[-1].x(),vertices[-1].y())

    points2d.insert(0,start) # prepend start point
    points = [QgsPoint(start[0],start[1])]
    i = 0
    n = 0
    b = -90
    for point in points2d[1:]:
        pt1 = QgsPoint(points2d[i][0],points2d[i][1])
        pt2 = QgsPoint(point[0],point[1])
        a = pt1.azimuth(pt2) + b
        pt = pt2.project(offset, a)
        points.append(pt)
        i += 1
        n += 1
        if n == len(dist):
            n = 0
            b = -b

    points.append(QgsPoint(end[0],end[1])) # append end point
    return QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points)
```

Answer (score 2):

To find out how many interior rings there are you need to use `num_interior_rings` and then make use of `interior_ring_n` to fetch each one in turn.

Comment: Thanks Ian- How would I write the expression so that it will apply the style to features with 0, 1 and 2 interior rings? Right now if I tell it to show an interior ring it turns off all the polygons without an interior ring.

Comment: see the answer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/370296/79 for a function to do just this

Comment: See my new customLineStyle solution for all possible geometry types:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376411/custom-qgis-linestyle-expression-function-wont-work-with-multilines/376503#376503