# How to create "wave styled" lines in geoserver SLD style?

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I nees to stylize lines with a style like the image below:

[image]

as seen in nautical charts.
Already read the "geoserver cookbook" but can't found anything useful.

Comment: Related, but using a different technology: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241802/drawing-wavy-wiggly-lines-in-qgis/241825#241825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `graphicStoke` to use the image along the lines.