# Creating wavy line in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, line, visualisation, geometry-generator

I'm looking for a way to quickly transform simple lines into wavy, zigzag lines and so on in QGIS. I already tried to use the method reported by @christoph in a question posted in this forum ([Drawing wavy, wiggly lines in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354873/131750)) but I can't make it work.

In ArcGIS this is a default option, I would like to make it so easy to apply it to my projects as well.

the results I'd like to achieve are these:

[image: wavy and zigzag lines]

Comment: What do you mean by "Cant make it work"? Have you even tried?

Comment: @BERA Of course I tried, otherwise I wouldn't have submitted the question. Following the passages reported in that answer the value returned to me by the geometry generator is NULL. I can't understand if I'm doing it wrong or if there's another problem.

Comment: worked for me- @ddomizia did you ever figure it out?

Comment: some problem, NULL is returend and no lines are rendered.