# Topology-aware "waviness" for polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, topology, geometry-generator

I am wondering if there is any chance to create "wavy" polygons that respect the topology. In a polygon-layer where the individual features shares boundaries you can easily style each feature and make it look wavy like so:

[image]

But I am wondering if there is any chance to create this waviness (or any other (maybe random) modification to the shape) outline while making sure they don't overlap. I really do not know if that is even possible or what kind of math you would need. Just asking if anyone else wondered about this before and might have an idea.

This very basic project from the image above is in the geopackage here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1AEKu4TKpzJg95oXv8dxep24xpXaesr0F

Comment: Your question, with certain limitations, is implemented using the Postgres/PostGIS software environment...

Comment: thanks!:) Any tip on what to look for there?

Comment: If you find it hard to understand the behavior of geoSQL functions, then post an additional question with a PostGIS tag, if you figure it out on your own, then use the link to the function :-)... https://github.com/CM-FOGS/PostgreSQL-PostGIS-GeoSQL-functions-/blob/main/ST_WavyLineEven_round

Comment: Thanks so much:) just a quick question: I guess it's also possible to run and try out all these functions in qgis somehow?:)

Comment: Not ready to confirm this possibility, but if SQLite has anologous functions and types of geodata, it is possible...

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/241802/120129